# How to show user improvement over time - mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table of users `moods`, they all have a `feeling` and `timestamp`. I want to write a query to show a users mood improvments or otherwise over time.

I figured i would start by converting the `feeling` into an integer score like so

```
SELECT 
    user_uuid, 
    feeling_at,
    feeling as `feeling_string`, 
    CASE feeling WHEN 'great' THEN 5 WHEN 'good' THEN 4 WHEN 'okay' THEN 3 WHEN 'bad' THEN 2 WHEN 'awful' THEN 1 END as `feeling_score`
FROM mood
WHERE feeling IN ('great', 'good', 'okay', 'bad', 'awful')
```

Sample response, there is actually millions or rows

```
1, 2019-02-05 16:26:57, great,  5
1, 2018-11-08 00:00:00, bad,    2
1, 2018-11-09 00:00:00, bad,    2
1, 2018-11-22 23:59:59, bad,    2
1, 2019-02-05 16:46:00, good,   4
1, 2018-11-08 23:59:59, great,  5
1, 2018-11-09 23:59:59, great,  5
2, 2019-02-06 15:25:00, okay,   3
2, 2019-02-06 15:25:00, bad,    2
3, 2019-02-05 23:59:59, awful,  1
3, 2019-02-06 16:49:00, bad,    2
```

Do you have any insight on a good way to split/group/compare a users earlier scores with later scores?

I don't know if you could compare the score of the users first X entries with last X entries
or first half vs second half?

Or some other approach to show if the users are generally feeling better or worse as they add more entries.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

**Updated with sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE mood(
  user_uuid char(36),
  feeling varchar(191),
  feeling_at timestamp
);

CREATE PROCEDURE bulk_insert()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= 10000 DO
        INSERT INTO moods VALUES (
                    ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 6, 'user1-uuid','user2-uuid','user3-uuid','user4-uuid','user5-uuid','user6-uuid'),
                    ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 5, 'great','good','okay','bad','awful') ,
                    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-04-30 14:53:27') + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 63072000)))
                );
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

In regards to #3 expected outcome, i have no hard requirement it will depend on possible solution to show changes of mood score over time.

I suppose something like this could work

```
+---------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
|   user_uuid   |  improved  |   early_scores  |    later_scores  |     
+---------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
|   user1-uuid  |     1      |       765       |        1435      |
|   user2-uuid  |     0      |       454       |        167       |
+---------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

and then from there, perhaps an outer query to get the percentage of users who have improved.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3

Comment: ok @Akina i have added some data for this thanks

Comment: I see neither CREATE TABLE nor INSERT INTO script.. Also I cannot understand how does the shown desired output is obtained from the shown source data.